# Nose test single setup function called once

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

How do I create a single setup function all my nose test cases that is only called once during initialization? I have a global configuration that only needs to be set once and I feel that adding the following to each module (even calling a setup function for each module) is a bit superfluous:

```
def setUp(self):
    Configuration.configure('some configuration settings')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out! Nose provides package-level setup and teardown as documented [here](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html). All I have to do is define the `setup` method in the package's `__init__.py` file.

[Here](https://github.com/TimKam/sphinx-pretty-searchresults/blob/master/tests/test_remove_markup.py), you can see an example of how to use the `setup` function. To make things simple:

```
lines = []
def setup():
    global lines
    lines.append('test') # here, we can trigger a build
                         # and read in a file, for example

def test_this():
    assert lines[0] == 'test'
```

Comment: Oh, example please? I've referenced the linked doc page many times.  I'm using nosetest "test functions" (not classes), and @with_setup decorators to setup the tests. But right now in the main test, I'm running pages of assert_equals in the same test_foobar(): when I should break these up into multiple test_foo1(), test_foo2() etc.